# Github Pages not showing up

Tags: github, github-pages

https://github.com/jchu4483/auth0

I'm following Github's tutorial to host a Github Page. I creating the repo and set the Github Page to track my **main branch** and published the Page.

Github says my site should be published at http://test-blog-on-qa.com/auth0/ but the site doesn't load. As a side note: Why would Github choose that weird domain name(test-blog-on-qa)?

I've chosen a theme(Jekyll), pushed an empty commit to rebuild but nothing works. This should be very simple so I'm confused as to what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [Github Custom Domain](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/about-custom-domains-and-github-pages) for your site [chu4483.github.io](https://github.com/jchu4483/jchu4483.github.io).

Have a look at: https://github.com/jchu4483/jchu4483.github.io/blob/master/CNAME

That's why `test-blog-on-qa.com` is used as the domain name automatically.

Comment: Can't believe myself, but thank you! I was so confused.